# bash cat pipe supposedly misbehaving

Tags: bash, stream, pipe, cat

In the following, I have made **echo to write to stderr**; then it's **piped to cat**, which has both output streams **connected to /dev/null**.

```
$ echo something 1>&2 | cat 2>&1 >/dev/null
something
```

All in all, nothing should be printed. As it turns out, **something** still gets printed!

Can someone please explain what's happening here? TY.

Comment: Hi @Ankyr - pretty sure the pipe only deals with fd 1 (the stdout) - so you've just redirected the output of the echo to fd 2 (the shell stderr) and then effectively done `cat </dev/null 2>&1 > /dev/null` for the rest

Comment: stderr is not piped to `cat`, the redirect sends it straight to the terminal (bypassing the pipe entirely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you write the output to `stderr`, it displays the output. If you would write it to `stdout`, it would not display the output.
This image from the wikipedia article about pipes explains it very well

[image: Pipeline Flow from wikipedia]

For more information read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) about Pipelines in Linux.